# Inline creation in backpack laravel

Tags: inline, laravel-backpack

I try to put an inline create on the field Application but it doesn't work
Is it due to the traisStore, here is the declaration in AppliCrudController

```
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation { store as traitStore; }
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\InlineCreateOperation { store as traitStore; }
```

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Could you answer to my issue please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the error your Chrome Developer Tools. That will provide more info.

Open Chrome Developer Tools, choose the Network tab, then submit the form again, so Chrome gets to track your AJAX request. That request will then show up in Chrome DevTools, click it to see so you can see what error it was, under Preview or Response.